# Render Callback for Angular Components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-changedetection

Is there a way to register a callback for whenever the component gets redrawn/re-rendered?

For eg. to count how many times the component was updated on the DOM?

I'm using `OnPush` change detection.

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss']
})
```

But if I'm not wrong, when the inputs to the component are updated, the component gets automatically redrawn, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're mostly right and you want to hook yourself into `ngOnChanges`.

Quoting [from their docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks):

> Respond when Angular sets or resets data-bound input properties. The method receives a SimpleChanges object of current and previous property values.
> Note that this happens very frequently, so any operation you perform here impacts performance significantly. See details in Using change detection hooks in this document.